# Robocopy command to copy multiple files but just the files not the dirs containing the files

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I was researching but there's no answer about a command in `Robocopy` to do the following:

I want to copy in a single folder all `*.log` files *(just the file not the directory that contain the file)* from multiple folders in a single path.

The source tree is the folowing:

```
c:\QA\1\1.log 
c:\QA\2\2.log 
c:\QA\3\3.log 
c:\QA\4\4.log
```

... and so on ...

e.g.

```
Source: c:\QA
Destination: c:\QA\LOG
File: *.log
```

I made this batch file but it also copies the folders which contain the files.

```
@echo
ROBOCOPY C:\QA\ C:\QA\LOG\ *.log /s
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is the solution, thanks to Chris Nathaniel

batch file:

```
@echo
for /R C:\QA\ %%f in (*.log) do copy %%f C:\QA\LOG\
pause
```

cmd.exe:

```
for /R C:\QA\ %f in (*.log) do copy %f C:\QA\LOG\
```